# ColdFusion 8 Upgrade License

Tags: coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Is it possible to upgrade the developer's edition of ColdFusion 7MX to ColdFusion 8 using a upgrade license instead of a full license?

Answer (score 1):

The developer version of both CF7 and 8 is a free license.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible, since the Developer editions don't cost anything. You can only upgrade from a Standard or Enterprise license.